# How to Invite user in Azure AD Programmaticaly using Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient sdk

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-b2b

I am trying to invite a user in Azure B2B Active directory. I am not able to find a way to do that using Client SDK.

Is there a possible way to do that?

Thanks for your help in advance. :)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a possible way to do that?

I can't find a method to invite a user with [Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient/).

But we could do that with 
[Microsoft.Graph](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph). And Azure official document also recommend that you use Microsoft Graph instead of [Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api).

> We strongly recommend that you use Microsoft Graph instead of Azure AD Graph API to access Azure Active Directory resources.
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api

I also do a demo for it. I works correctly on my side.

Before that I create the Web application in the Azure directory. Add required **Invite guest users to the organization** permission for Microsoft Graph

[image]

Demo code:

```
string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}";
string graphResourceId = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
string tenantId = "tenant id";
string clientId = "client Id";
string secret = "sercet key";
authority = String.Format(authority, tenantId);
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
var accessToken = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceId, new ClientCredential(clientId, secret)).Result.AccessToken;
var graphserviceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                    requestMessage =>
                    {
                        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }));
var dic = new Dictionary<string, object> {{"@odata.type", "microsoft.graph.invitedUserMessageInfo"}};

Invitation invitation = new Invitation
            {
                InvitedUserEmailAddress = "email address",
                InvitedUserMessageInfo = new InvitedUserMessageInfo{AdditionalData = dic },
                InvitedUserDisplayName = "xxx",
                SendInvitationMessage = false,
                InviteRedirectUrl = "xxxxx"

            };
 var result = graphserviceClient.Invitations.Request().AddAsync(invitation).Result;
```

[image]

Comment: How can we delete the user using the same client SDK you are talking about?