# Inviting a User in Azure AD through Microsoft Graph API doesn't work

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Below is the code that I have put to invite a user in Azure AD.

I get an "unauthorized" response. I am not sure what permission/setting are missing. Do anyone have the idea.

```cs
string accessToken = await AuthenticationHelper.GetTokenForApplication ();
InvitationModel invite = new InvitationModel ();
invite.invitedUserEmailAddress = user.Email;
invite.inviteRedirectUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InviteRedirectUrl"];
invite.sendInvitationMessage = true;
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient ()) {
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri ("https://graph.microsoft.com");

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add (
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue ("application/json"));

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
        new AuthenticationHeaderValue ("Bearer", accessToken);

    HttpResponseMessage response =
        client.PostAsJsonAsync<InvitationModel> ("v1.6/invitations", invite).Result;

    dynamic inviteResult =
        response.Content.ReadAsAsync<dynamic> ().Result;

    if (inviteResult.status != "Error") { }
}
```

Comment: v1.6? You might be mixing Azure AD Graph and Microsoft Graph. MS Graph versions at the moment are v1.0 and beta AFAIK.

Comment: @juunas I have replaced it with v1.0 but I still get the Unauthorized error. what could be that I am missing.

Comment: message : Access token validation failure

Comment: I have made few changes and now see this error

Insufficient privileges to perform requested operation by the application '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'. ControllerName=MSGraphInviteAPI, ActionName=CreateInvite

But i do have given the right permission to read/write AD data to the application from azure portal.

Comment: I have added the code sample in you another [so thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48093480/how-to-invite-user-in-azure-ad-programmaticaly-using-microsoft-azure-activedirec/48419406#48419406).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're problem is that you conflating Microsoft Graph and Azure AD Graph here. These are two distinct APIs with different calling conversions and permission scopes.

In order to [create an Invitation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/invitation_post) you will need one of the following [permission scopes](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference) (*Note that the first is the most restrictive permission (globally), the last the most permissive*):

- `User.Invite.All`
- `User.ReadWrite.All`
- `Directory.ReadWrite.All`

*Note that all of these scopes are admin-restricted and will require [Admin Consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-scopes#admin-restricted-scopes) before you can use them*

Once you have a valid token, you'll need to make a `POST`call to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/invitations` with the following body:

```js
{
  "invitedUserEmailAddress": "yyy@test.com",
  "inviteRedirectUrl": "https://myapp.com"
}
```

Since you're using C#, I would strongly recommend using [Microsoft Graph Client Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph) rather than hand-rolling your own `HttpClient` calls.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have link to the sample code of Microsoft Graph Client Library, because I dont find any

Comment: There are a lot of samples available at https://github.com/microsoftgraph/ but I'd suggest starting with the [UWP Snippets](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/uwp-csharp-snippets-sample) sample first. Even if you're not using UWP, the C# code in there should be portable enough. It's also a great sandbox to play around with the SDK.

Comment: Thanks, this solution did also work for me in an Azure PowerShell Runbook scenario with New-AzureADMSInvitation

Comment: FYI for anybody looking for this solution. Azure AD Graph is now deprecated and everybody should be using the Microsoft Graph API