# Adding B2B Guest users in a group for Application access

Tags: azure-active-directory

I want to invite external users to access few applications in my Azure AD tenant. I have used Graph API to sent bulk invite to the users.Now,in order to display the applications in the AD access panel for the users, I need to provide them access to the applications. I think the approach would be creating a group of guest users and assign the group to the applications.

How can I add the guest users in a group while sending invite?
Does the invitation API provide any optional parameter to add the invited user in a group?

Also, can I assign the application(s) permission to the guest user or a guest user group through API in time of sending invitation?

Any code sample will help.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the invitation API provide any optional parameter to add the invited user in a group?

No, there is no any optional paramter to add the invited use in a group using [create invitation API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/invitation_post).

The following is the Rest API how to invite external users.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/invitations
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 551

{
  "invitedUserEmailAddress": "yyy@test.com",
  "inviteRedirectUrl": "https://myapp.com"
}
```

You also could get more information about how to use this API from this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48095484/inviting-a-user-in-azure-ad-through-microsoft-graph-api-doesnt-work).
If C# code is possible, you could refer to this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48093480/how-to-invite-user-in-azure-ad-programmaticaly-using-microsoft-azure-activedirec/48419406#48419406).

> can I assign the application(s) permission to the guest user

Sure, we could use following api to do that.

```
POST https://graph.windows.net/{tenantId}/directoryObjects/{userObjectId}/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User/appRoleAssignments?api-version=1.6
```

Body

```
{
"odata.type":"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.AppRoleAssignment",
"id":"ApplicationId",
"principalId":"userObjectId",
"principalType":"User",
"resourceId":"ServiceprincipalObjectId"
}
```

If C# code is possible, you could refer to this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52011625/issue-with-remove-application-role-in-azuread-using-graphapi-c-sharp/52035691#52035691).